# Struggling with theorem proof involving only disjunctions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Been stuck on this question, any help would be appreciated. I haven't been able to derive any of the atomics to get me further in my proof. Here's the question.

Given that...

```
r v p
r v q
s v ~p v ~q
```

Show that...

```
~r => s
```

Comment: I can get to q => ~p v s but I don't have q in order to finish the proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\lnot r$. Since $r\lor p$, we must have $p$. Since $r\lor q$, we must have $q$. Since $s\lor \lnot p\lor \lnot q$, we must have $s$. Thus $\lnot r\rightarrow s$.

Comment: Is there a way to get ~r with the three premises?

Comment: To prove $\lnot r \rightarrow s$, you can assume $\lnot r$ and prove $s$.

Comment: The comment by @cxcharm leads me to guess that the question was intended in the context of some particular deductive system. But of course, if that was the intention, then the particular system should have been specified.

Comment: I believe the system would just be propositional calculus/logic. I may have misunderstood the question, but it seems to me like I’m being asked to use the three premises to prove the conclusion, and so assuming a fourth premise wouldn’t work unless it was in the context of a conditional derivation or proof by contradiction or something like that. However, if the question is impossible as I’ve presented it, then I may have just misunderstood it.

Comment: @cxcharm Andreas's comment is right: if my answer doesn't satisfy you, you'll have to be more specific about what you mean by "propositional calculus/logic". There are many different proof systems for classical propositional logic - they prove the same entailments, but the form that proofs take differs from system to system.

Answer (score 1):

1. $(r\lor p)\land(r\lor q)\land(s\lor\neg p\lor \neg q)\implies(\neg r\implies s)$
2. $(r\lor p)\land(r\lor q)\land(s\lor\neg p\lor \neg q)\land\neg r\implies s$
3. $(r\lor (p\land q))\land(s\lor\neg p\lor \neg q)\land\neg r\implies s$
4. $(p\land q)\land(s\lor\neg p\lor \neg q)\land\neg r\implies s$
5. $(p\land q)\land(s\lor\neg (p\land q))\land\neg r\implies s$
6. $p\land q\land s\land\neg r\implies s$
7. true

Let me know if you need more clarifications on any of the steps